# Exit Event when move to other frame in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I trying to get an event when move from one frame to another in AS3.

I have tried with the `EXIT_FRAME` it always calling.
I need to get state when move from one frame to another.

```
addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME,exitfunc); 
function exitfunc(e:Event):void{
 trace("EXIT_FRAME");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move from one frame to another"? An example would help.

Answer (score 1):

as Nagarajan sugges, you can dynamically add a script to a frame.

For example in your main class

```
package {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;

  public class Test extends MovieClip
  {
      public function Test()
      {
          this.addFrameScript(4,frameFunction); // (add script to frame 5, zero based)
      }

      private function frameFunction():void {
          trace ('Do something when play head enters frame 4')
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: addFrameScript does also remove any code that was previously in that frame so it's not a very flexible solution for people adding code to frames directly as it's the case here.

Comment: True a drawback is the complete removeall of any code adding to that frame before, but why -1 for the answer? It depends on the case if that's a problem. Maybe Vineesh TP has knows nobody else is adding code to the frame?

Answer (score 0):

because their names are misleading.  Event.EXIT_FRAME doesn't execute once when the playhead exits a frame.  it executes repeatedly.

likewise, Event.ENTER_FRAME doesn't execute once when the playhead enters a frame.  it executes repeatedly.

you can execute a function when the playhead enters a a frame by adding a function call to the frame:

f();  // attached to a frame will call the function f when the playhead enters this frame.  and there are other ways to do this.

you can execute a function when a playhead exists a frame by invalidating the stage and using a render event when a goto is executed:

```
stage.invaidate();
this.addEventListener(Event.RENDER,ExitingF);
this.gotoAndPlay('whatever');
function exitingF(e:Event):void{
     // this code executes when this frame is exited and 'whatever' is rendered
    (=displayed);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There's only one good way but that might be beyond your skill level. Create a class that extends MovieClip and override the gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay methods then simply make them dispatch a custom event (don't forget the call to super). That custom event can carry the frame label, index, etc ... You'll have to make sure your MovieClips/Document class implement that class and everything will be done automatically. 
This will allow you to keep track of when you leave a frame and move to another with a call to gotoAndStop or gotoAndPlay. If you only want to keep track of normal playhead move then the ENTER_FRAME event is enough.

Comment: And what if somebody just call myMovieclip.play() or nobody calls a 'play, gotoAndPlay() or gotoAndStop()' to the movieclip, and there's no stop in the first frame of the movieclip? Flash just continue looping the movieclip without notify the program exit or entering any frame

Comment: That's why I said if that's the case enter frame is better suited for that purpose.